# Excel VBA evaluate formula from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, eval

**Solved: The problem is in my formula where I'm referencing a cell using INDIRECT() which doesn't work when sheet is different. See answer.**

I have a formula in one sheet and what I want to do is to use the formula from another sheet, using eval to evaluate the formula. However, the result is not as intended. It seems like the formula is using values at Sheet A instead of the caller Sheet B.

Formula in sheet A (See: [Screenshot Sheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8UJN.png))

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('1516Activity'!$B:$B,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) )),'1516Activity'!$C:$C,0))),"-",IF(LEFT(INDEX('1516Activity'!$F:$F,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) )),'1516Activity'!$C:$C,0)))="0","N","Y"))
```

Usage in Sheet B (See: [Screenshot Sheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bJ8O.png))

```
=Eval('CODE-VARS'!$G$5)
```

VBA:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I'm referencing a cell using INDIRECT() which doesn't work when the eval() is called from a different sheet.

This works:

```
INDEX(D:D,ROW())
```

This doesn't:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating the String `'CODE-VARS'!$G$5` which would return the value in that cell not its formula.  Try this:

```
Function Eval(Ref As RAnge)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref.formula)
End Function
```

Comment: Tried and it's still the same

Comment: Could it be something in my formula that references to value at the reffered sheet instead of the caller/active sheet? 
`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))`

Comment: What values are in column D?  The Indirect(Address())  expects a cell reference to be in Column D.  So show some example of what is in column D. @ZhuHang

Comment: Wothout seeing your data, I think what you want instead of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))` is `INDEX(D:D,ROW)`

Comment: Screenshot of both sheets added to my question.

Comment: @ZhuHang see the last comment I made.  change all the INDIRECT parts for the INDEX function.

Comment: Yes that worked out for me! Change `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))` to `INDEX(D:D,ROW())`
Thanks so much! A noob question because I'm new here, how to mark comment as answer?

Comment: @ZhuHang please mark as correct.  Click on the grey/green check mark by the answer.

Comment: Can you post a new answer about replacing with INDEX()? That should be exact solution! :) I'll mark that one as answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it references values in whatever sheet is active.

In your `Eval` function,  ensure the target sheet is active:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Dim shCurrent As Worksheet: Set shCurrent = ActiveSheet
    Application.Volatile
    Application.ThisCell.Parent.Activate
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
    shCurrent.Activate
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot use Activate inside a UDF

Comment: Correct.  I was thinking of `Sub`.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams @yk11
Using the function I stated in question, I added this:
`MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` 
and it shows the caller sheet name. So I think its not this issue. Could it be something in my formula that references to value at the reffered sheet instead of the caller/active sheet?
`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))`

Comment: INDIRECT is probably Excel's most evil function and should not be used. Its not clear to me what you are trying to achieve but it looks as though you should be able to replace it with a simple cell reference. What row do you want your UDF to reference?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams The row depends on which cell I use the formula, the column is always 'D'. That is why I reference to `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(D:D) ))`

Comment: So why can't you replace the INDIRECT(...) with $D5   ? or in R1C1 mode use RC4 ?

Comment: #Charles Because this formula is gonna call by many different rows, I can't fix it at D5, it will be something like:  <br/>
- K18(calling eval) > formula refers to D18  <br/>
- K29(calling eval) > formula refers to D29 <br/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Application.Caller:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```