# Excel Eval within Eval

Tags: vba, excel, eval

I'm using custom eval function in VBA. However, evaluating a formula which contains another eval() fails:

```
=Eval(I21)
```

Cell I21: (formula itself works) Note: INDIRECT() doesnt work too

```
'=MATCH("SOME TEXT",eval($I$22),0)
```

Cell I22: (location reference)

```
''1516Activity'!$C:$C
```

VBA:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Comment: I think you should remove the "=" in cell I21 (formula). For the recursion (eval in eval) you might need to write your own parser.

Comment: @Gerfried Mind elaborating it further? Thanks!

Comment: It should work if you use `Eval = Application.Evaluate(Ref)` but you'll need to make sure you pass fully qualified range addresses.

Comment: @Rory Yes, it works. But only in same sheet. If I want to evaluate it from another sheet, how to achieve same effect as `ThisCell.Parent` ?

Comment: Like I said - use fully qualified addresses, not just I21.

Comment: @Rory I have `INDEX($D:$D,ROW())` in my new formula and I'm evaluating from another sheet. `=EVAL('SheetA'!$A$1)`

Comment: `ROW()` has no context to work from - you need to pass it a cell, and the $D:$D needs a sheet too.

Comment: @Rory I want the row to dependent on caller row. So it means it can't have a fully qualified address?

Comment: You just can't do that. `Evaluate` is not a range method. Why do you (think you) need this level of indirection?

Comment: @Rory It works with `ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate()` except the eval within eval thing. The whole purpose is I want to keep all formulas in one sheet for easy maintainence. Refer the screenshots here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825742/excel-vba-evaluate-formula-from-another-sheet/

Comment: Which row number are you expecting it to use? The row number of the cell with `Eval` in it, or the row number of the cell containing the `ROW()` string?

Comment: @Rory Let me ignore the question, this formula: `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('1516Activity'!$C:$C,MATCH(INDEX($D:$D,ROW()),'1516Activity'!$C:$C,0))),'CODE-VARS'!$F13,IF(LEFT(INDEX('1516Activity'!$F:$F,MATCH(INDEX($D:$D,ROW()),'1516Activity'!$C:$C,0)))="0",'CODE-VARS'!$G13,'CODE-VARS'!$E13))` is working using VBA: ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(). It can be used from another sheet by: `=eval('SheetA'!$A$1)` I now wish to replace sheet name in formula with a reference cell holding a modifiable sheet name.

Comment: So build the formula string up using concatenation. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the original problem though.

Comment: @Rory original problem solved using Application.Evaluate() but not applicable for my scenario where formula is self-referencing to caller cell. 

If I use CONCATENATE, I'll need `eval(concatenate(...))` which goes back to the original problem of eval within eval.

Comment: @Rory Can you post your previous comment as an answer?
"It should work if you use Eval = Application.Evaluate(Ref) but you'll need to make sure you pass fully qualified range addresses. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA:

```
Eval = Application.Evaluate(Ref)
```

This solution only works when cell-reference uses fully qualified range addresses. If your reference depends on caller ( involves row()+- and column()+- ), then you are in the same situation as me, no solution.