# Excel VBA Evaluate Function Wrong When Reference is Not Active Sheet for Named Range

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate, named-ranges

**EDITED WITH BETTER EXAMPLE**

I'm trying to use the Evaluate function to evaluate a formula reference for a named range. However, when using the Evaluate function, if you do not explicitly state the sheet reference along with the cell reference, it will assume the active sheet as the cell reference. This causes the wrong result

In my real project I'm trying to only evaluate a part of the named range's formula, so it makes it even trickier.

Using a basic example of what I'm trying to do, let's say you have the following formula in Sheet 1 cell A1 whose name is MyCell:

```
="Don't evaluate this part"&"My Result Is " & A2
```

If the Active Sheet is Sheet 2 and you run the following code it will give you the wrong results (this is a quick and dirty example to illustrate the problem)

```
Dim s As String
s = Replace(Range("MyCell").Formula, """Don't evaluate this part""&", "")
Debug.Print Evaluate(s)
```

Instead of giving me the value that is in cell A2 of Sheet 1, it gives me the value that is in cell A2 of Sheet2.

Any ideas around this?

This is closest I found, but it is not my exact problem (despite similar titles) and it doesn't provide a solution:
[Excel VBA evaluate formula from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825742/excel-vba-evaluate-formula-from-another-sheet)

Comment: Is cell A1 in Sheet 2 named MyCell? Are you always evaluating exactly the formula in a cell? As in... is there a reason you aren't just checking the value of that cell instead of the formula?

Comment: Excel is operating by design and as necessary. If you can't just grab the value as mentioned in my first comment, it gets a little trickier but there are ways to do it

Comment: To better illustrate what I mean see my newer example.

Comment: To answer your questions. 1) Cell A1 in Sheet 2 is NOT named MyCell. Instead, Cell A1 in Sheet 1 is named MyCell.  2) I'm evaluating parts of the formula (see my edits above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nearly always better to use Worksheet.Evaluate rather than the default Application.Evaluate: as Mark Balhoff points out that allows you to control unqualified references.
But Worksheet.Evaluate is also usually twice as fast as Application.Evaluate.
See my blog post here for details
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/

Comment: Great. I'll check it out and see if that helps in my project. Thanks.  By the way, I've read and am using your Excel-DNA instructions Great stuff. =)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that by design Excel will assume all unspecific cell references are referring to the existing worksheet. This is why whenever possible it is recommended to explicitly state the worksheet in all code.

The cleanest way (verified with some MSDN definintion hunting) is to just explicitly state the worksheet without activating it:

```
Sub test2()
    Debug.Print Range("MyCell").Worksheet.Evaluate(Range("MyCell").Formula)
End Sub
```

Alternatively this code will change the active worksheet to the correct one and then change it back after evaluation. **Not recommended to perform sheet activations like the code below without extenuating circumstances. Not even here.**

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace(Range("MyCell").Formula, """Don't evaluate this part""&", "")
    Range("MyCell").Worksheet.Activate  ' Don't remember if .Worksheet or .Parent ??
    Debug.Print Evaluate(s)
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

As pointed out in the comments by ThunderFrame, it is important to remember that this code assumes MyCell is a simple cell reference as stated in the question. Otherwise you will need to use other methods to determine the target worksheet name (or hardcode it).

Comment: I understand this is by design and I understand that explicitly stating the sheet reference within the original formula will avoid the issue. By this is being sent out to users who I cannot control how they will input their formula.  Anyway, I was just think about doing exactly what you proposes. This will be my back up plan as I'm afraid of performance. In my real project their could be 100s to 1000s of cells with formulas like that. I'm hesitant to activate the sheet for each one. But ultimately this could work.

Comment: @ptownbro Use the shorter code. That **_won't_** actually activate the sheet.

Comment: @ptownbro In reality activation and selection should be avoided 99.999% of the time so just use the shorter code every time to avoid that.

Comment: You might need to check if the defined name is defined as a literal (as opposed to a cell reference). For example a name `Foo` defined as `="Bar"` will not have a formula or a worksheet property using the Evaluate or Range approach.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Good point. The OP did state "Sheet 1 cell A1 whose name is MyCell" so in his specific case my code works. But in the effort of a general Q&A site perhaps I should note that. As far as actually implementing that accomodation, you would either have to hardcode the desired worksheet or know how to get it from the literal.

Comment: Indeed, it's an edge-case, but if you don't know where a user is pointing their names, or you're enumerating all of  the names, you'd need to deal with those edge cases.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks guys for all your help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

`Debug.Print Evaluate(Range("MyCell").Formula)`

is equivalent to:

`Debug.Print Evaluate("=""My Result Is "" & A2")`

which is why you get results according to the value of A2 in the ActiveSheet.

If you want to inspect the contents of the formula, you can use this line:

`Debug.Print [MyCell].Formula`

If you want the value of MyCell with respect to Sheet1, then you have 2 options:

1 - Use `Debug.Print Range("Sheet1!MyCell").Value`

2 - Use `Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("MyCell").Value`

Comment: Not sure you see the same question as me. He wants to execute a modified version of the formula in the cell. You've told him how to get the cell value and how to display the unevaluated formula but not how to execute a modified formula on a non-active sheet.

Comment: Yeah, in an earlier edit of the question, I interpreted the question as evaluating the formula text, as opposed to evaluating the formula result.

Comment: Fair enough. I know what you mean. That's the first impression I had. Only reason I knew what was going on was because I had asked OP for clarification. Then again... I've been completely off-base before even after getting lots of "clarification".

Comment: I work on VBA Rubberduck, so I'm too used to parsing formulas :-\

Comment: Nice yea hard to frequent these tags and not know of that project. Seems like a nice project that I still need to download. I try to avoid parsing formulas manually because it's a pain but I did write some pretty clean code once to generically parse excel formulas (functions, named ranges, arrays, etc). For some reason that was kind of fun... ;)

Comment: Rubberduck is more about the VBA, but there's a nice github project for [formulas](https://github.com/spreadsheetlab/XLParser) too